# curl in php - how to get obtained data as array or other resource

Tags: php, curl

```
    $url = "myurl";

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    $passwordStr = "$this->username:$this->password"; 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $passwordStr);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("Content-type: application/atom+xml"));

    $successCode = 200;

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

curl_exec obtains xml data from myurl, as expected, but simply echoes it in the output buffer. The value of `$return` is a simple boolean. Instead, I would like it to return the obtained xml data as an array or any other php object that I can process (without having to do any cumbersome `ob_start` output buffering). Is this possible or is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php:

> CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER    TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to use `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option to return your response rather than `echoing` it.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

after that, you may need to use [*`SimpleXMLElement`*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to parse your xml into an array :

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$resultArray = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
```

**SimpleXMLElement** will return an instance of SimpleXMLElement object.

---

another option of parsing your xml into an array by using [*`xml_parse_into_struct`*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php) :

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($parse, $result, $values, $indexes);
xml_parser_free($parser);

// then you can access your array values using $values,$indexes variables
print_r($values);
```